# Create Report in Embed View via PowerBI API

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to create a new report from a dataset in an embedded view. However, I keep getting "This content isn't available" and the reportEmbed.min.js returning a 403 on render. Within app.powerbi.com I can successfully create and save reports, but as mentioned above the embedded view is not working.

I am following this documentation exactly:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Create-Report-in-Embed-View

However, I am generating my embed token via a Power BI API call as documentation allows here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt784614.aspx

Here is my server-side, embedToken generation code:

```
const createReportEmbedTokenForCreation = ({
  accessToken,
  groupId,
  datasetId,
}) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = `https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/${groupId}/reports/GenerateToken`;
    const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  };
  const form = {
    accessLevel: 'Create',
    datasetId,
    allowSaveAs: true,
  };
  request.post({ url, form, headers }, (err, result, body) => {
    if (err) return reject(err);
    const bodyObj = JSON.parse(body);
    if (bodyObj.error) return reject(new Error(body));
    return resolve(bodyObj.token);
  });
});
```

Here is my client-side embed code:

```
const config = {
  accessToken: embedToken,
  embedUrl: 'https://embedded.powerbi.com/appTokenReportEmbed',
  datasetId: defaultReport.datasetId,
};
const report = powerbi.createReport(
  document.getElementById('ReportEmbed'),
  config,
);
```

Am I missing some scope some where?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To create a new report in the embed application. You will have to use the API -`GenerateTokeForCreateInGroup`.

So the server-side will look something like this:

```
// Generate an embed token to create
var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(
    TokenAccessLevel.Create,    
    “enter your datasetid”,    
    allowSaveAs: true    
);

var tokenResponse = client.Reports.GenerateTokenForCreateInGroup(“enter your workspaceid”, generateTokenRequestParameters);

// Populate embed variables (to be passed client-side)    
embedToken = tokenResponse.Token;    
embedUrl = “https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?groupId=” + “enter your workspaceid”;
datasetId = “enter your workspaceid”;
```

> Note: Row-Level Security is not supported for this API. Hence, no
> effective identity has been defined in GenerateTokenRequest.

Your client-side code will look something like this:

```
// Read embed token
var embedToken = “<% = this.embedToken %>”;

// Read embed URL
var embedUrl = “<% = this.embedUrl %>”;

// Read dataset Id
var datasetId = “<% = this.datasetId %>”;

// Get models (models contains enums)
var models = window[‘powerbi-client’].models;

// Embed configuration is used to describe what and how to embed
// This object is used when calling powerbi.embed
// It can also includes settings and options such as filters

var embedCreateConfiguration = {
    type: ‘report’,
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    accessToken: embedToken,
    embedUrl: embedUrl,
    datasetId: datasetId,
};

// Embed the report within the div element
var report = powerbi.createReport(embedDiv, embedCreateConfiguration);
var saveAsParameters = {
    name: “newReport”
};

// SaveAs report
report.saveAs(saveAsParameters);
```

For more information, you can refer to this blog: https://addendanalytics.com/create-a-new-report-in-embed-view/. Further, you can also refer to Microsoft's official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong embedURL...
AppTokenReportEmbed is the OLD (deprecated) Workspace Collection way.
Since you're using GenerateToken, please put the following embedURL:
'https://embedded.powerbi.com/reportEmbed'

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the following Embed URL:
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=MyReportID123&groupId=MyGroupID123; and provide the **ReportID** and the **GroupID** of the report you wish to embed.