# Create a Mobile Responsive Version of a PowerBI report that is Published to the Web

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I've recently published a specific PowerBI report and despite creating a 'Phone' View on PowerBI Desktop this didn't show up in the final embed code.

I've looked into PowerBI Embedded Playground and managed to generate the relevant access tokens and even try it out, but still couldn't figure out how to modify the code in such a way to generate a mobile view.

The questions and answers below somehow didn't give me the insight I needed, still somehow need some additional work:

[Mobile view is not being shown for embedded powerbi report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429373/mobile-view-is-not-being-shown-for-embedded-powerbi-report)

[Create Report in Embed View via PowerBI API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177971/create-report-in-embed-view-via-powerbi-api)

[Power BI RS web embedding in mobile web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56932306/power-bi-rs-web-embedding-in-mobile-web-browser)

What do I need to do to get started? Which documentation do I need to look into exactly? I need to embed this report in a Sharepoint 2010 Page and I need it to be mobile responsive on page load and not via a seperate link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't related to the access token in any way. It is generated before configuring the embedding process. To embed the report in phone view, you must specify [`MobilePortrait`](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile#embed-a-report-in-mobile-layout) layout type in the embed configuration, i.e. something like this:

```
var config = {
    .....
    settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: true,
        navContentPaneEnabled: true,
        layoutType: models.LayoutType.MobilePortrait <-- THIS ONE
    }
};
```

If you omit `layoutType`, it will be shown in the landscape view (i.e. like in the desktop). For more information about the configuration see [Embed Configuration Details](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Configuration-Details), and for embedding in general you should start from [Embedding Basics](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding-Basics).

Comment: Is embbedding in an app the same as embbeding an iframe in a web page? I want the layout to be dynamic/responsive

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot Every kind of embedding basically boils down to an iframe. I guess you are talking about [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web). If so, the answer is no - they are very different. Publish to web is very limited and in practice should never be used in production scenarios. Embedding in an application using the Power BI API is the most flexible and powerful way to do that, but it requires programming skills.